# If $f_n\to f$ pointwise on $[0,1]$, then $\sup_{[0,1]}f_n\to\sup_{[0,1]}f$ pointwise?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, pointwise-convergence

Let $\{f_n(x)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of bounded functions that converge pointwise on $[0,1]$ to some bounded function $f(x)$.

I am trying to determine whether it is true that $\sup_{x\in[0,1]}f_n(x)\to\sup_{x\in[0,1]}f(x)$ pointwise on $[0,1]$. I think it is, and here is my proof:

Let $x\in[0,1]$. Fix $\epsilon>0$. Obtain some $N$ so that for any $n>N$, $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$. Then, $f_n(x)-f(x)<\epsilon$ and $f(x)-f_n(x)<\epsilon$. Then, we have

$$f_n(x)-\sup_{x\in[0,1]}f(x)\le f_n(x)-f(x)<\epsilon\implies \sup_{x\in[0,1]}f_n(x)-\sup_{x\in[0,1]}f(x)\le f_n(x)-f(x)<\epsilon$$
$$f(x)-\sup_{x\in[0,1]}f_n(x)\le f(x)-f_n(x)<\epsilon\implies \sup_{x\in[0,1]}f(x)-\sup_{x\in[0,1]}f_n(x)\le f(x)-f_n(x)<\epsilon$$

It proves $|\sup_{x\in[0,1]}f_n(x)-\sup_{x\in[0,1]}f(x)|<\epsilon$.

Did I make any mistakes?

Comment: What is the meaning of asserting that a numerical sequence converges *pointwise* to a number?

Comment: you're confusing a number with a function, $\sup_{[0,1]}f_n$ is a number, not a function

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos oh thanks for pointing out. I didn't realize that $\{\sup_{[0,1]}f_n\}$ is not a sequence of functions. So it seems like my result is true regardless of whether $f_n\to f$ pointwise or uniform?

Answer (score 4):

Presumably the intended question was

- If $f_n\to f$ pointwise on $[0,1]$, must $\sup_{[0,1]}f_n\to\sup_{[0,1]}f$?

If so, the answer is "no".

For a counterexample, if we let
$$
f_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
1&\text{if}\;x={\large{\frac{1}{n}}}\\[4pt]
0&\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
$$
then $f_n\to 0$ pointwise, but $\sup_{[0,1]} f_n=1$ for all $n$.